# Lookup Function with Shared Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have 3 sub accounts for one client (per clients request) all of which are for different websites. I am trying to create a SHARED data extension for all accounts. The 3 accounts have full permissions to the DE. My content within the emails uses a Lookup Function to call the DE, and image url's I am storing within it. The syntax I am using is correct, but for some reason using the shared DE between the accounts does not parse out the html for the lookup function. Whereas if I create an **individual** DE for each account, everything then displays correctly. I cannot seem to determine the reason for this. Is there some issue with using the LOOKUP function when a shared Data Extension is involved?

All thoughts are helpful. Thanks.

Comment: is the Subscriber list same for all three DE. if not try it out with one SL.
Let me know if it works for you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#Enterprise_and_Enterprise_2.0_Accounts)

> **Enterprise and Enterprise 2.0 Accounts** When working with a data extension in the top level of an Enterprise or Enterprise 2.0 account
>   or with a shared data extension in an Enterprise 2.0 account, add the
>   prefix ENT. to the data extension.

I would suggest adding "ENT." to the shared DE name, and that should clear up your issue.